# assimp cmake mingw-w64 VSCode win10

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-code, windows-10, mingw-w64, assimp

**UPDATE**

later version of assimp (5.2.5) can be successfully built by mingw-w64 (gcc version 12.2.0) by disabling `ASSIMP_WARNING_AS_ERROR`.

However, it cannot load .obj model (the model doesn't show in the opengl scene) previously loaded by msvc built assimp.

[Assimp 5.2.5 compiled by cmake-gui and mingw-w64 faild to load .obj model in opengl rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235738/assimp-5-2-5-compiled-by-cmake-gui-and-mingw-w64-faild-to-load-obj-model-in-ope)

---

**UPDATE**: the developer of assimp has confirmed the bug and planned to fix it by adding this to `ToDo` in `Planning for Release V5.1` on 26 May.

https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/3221

---

I'm trying to use assimp in opengl, following building instructions here: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/Build.md under the following environment:

```
assimp 5.0.1    
cmake 3.17.2
mingw-w64 with gcc/g++ 8.1.0
VSCode in Win10
```

I tried in cmake-gui, use MinGW Makefile , I can obtain a makefile in the build path.

I then tried to make it by mingw32-make and stopped at 69% with

```
[ 67%] Linking CXX shared library libassimp.dll
[ 67%] Built target assimp
Scanning dependencies of target assimp_cmd
[ 67%] Building RC object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/assimp_cmd.rc.obj
[ 68%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/CompareDump.cpp.obj
[ 68%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/ImageExtractor.cpp.obj
[ 68%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/Main.cpp.obj
[ 68%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/WriteDumb.cpp.obj
[ 69%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/Info.cpp.obj
[ 69%] Building CXX object tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/Export.cpp.obj
[ 69%] Linking CXX executable assimp.exe
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ValidateFlags(unsigned int) const'
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*, Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::GetErrorString() const'
......
......
......
CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0xf44): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [tools\assimp_cmd\CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir\build.make:197: tools/assimp_cmd/assimp.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:297: tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Though I can get a "libassimp.dll" and a "libassimp.dll.a" in the build directory, I failed to link them into my project. there are many "undefined reference to xxxx" errors.

1. I placed the .dll in the exe path, placed .a file in lib path, placed all the assimp .h files in the include path.
2. VSCode doesn't seem to support the file name "libassimp.dll.a", I have to rename it as libassimpdll.a and write "-lassimp" in tasks.json. But "undefined reference" errors exists.
3. I tried to build assimp to VS2017 and I can get dll and lib.
4. I tried to directly link the assimp 3.1.1 (with x86/x64 dll and lib already provided officially) but also failed.

So my question is **if anyone succeed in building assimp with cmake and mingw-w64 and link it in the project in VSCode Win10?**

Comment: I recommend starting without VSCode – the fewer moving parts, the less headache. C++ objects and libraries from MSVC and GCC are incompatible. Could you enable verbose mode in the CMake+GCC build to see what's actually executed?

Comment: I've searched through stackoverflow and the main leader said that assimp doesn't seem to support to be built by mingw-w64 ...

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build assimp 5.0.1 with:

```
cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_HEADERCHECK:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF -DSYSTEM_IRRXML:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_win &&
make -Cbuild_win &&
echo Success
```

and even the same with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON` under the MSYS2 shell.

It doesn't work with `-DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=ON` though.

Comment: Thanks. But I've give up using mingw-w64 and turn to msvc for a while. Pity haven't seen this answer earlier. :-(